# Asp.net MVC TempData Getting Crossed / Mixed Up

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have used TempData to pass data between controllers. If two users are working on the same page, User2 will get the tempdata value which is created by User1.

Below you can find the code.

Can you please help me to solve this issue.

VDRController.cs

```
 public ActionResult RedirectToCDR(long VslMoveId, long VslVisitId, string VslNm, string ETDDtTmLoc, string statusCd)
    {
        //List<long> vslIds = new List<long>();
        string vslIds = VslMoveId + "," + VslVisitId.ToString() + "," + statusCd;
        TempData["VslMoveDetails"] = vslIds;
        //DateTime MyDateTime;
        //MyDateTime = new DateTime();
        var strdatetime = Convert.ToDateTime(ETDDtTmLoc).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        TempData["VslNameETD"] = VslNm + "  " + strdatetime;
        //return RedirectToAction("Index","VesselVisit");
        return Json(Url.Action("Index", "CDR"));

    }
```

CDRController.cs

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        if (TempData["VslMoveDetails"] != null)
        {
            string vslIds = TempData["VslMoveDetails"].ToString();
            string[] Ids = vslIds.Split(new char[] { ',' });
            if (Ids.Length == 3 && Ids[0] != null && Ids[1] != null)
            {
                ViewBag.VslMove_Id = Ids[0];
                ViewBag.VslVisit_Id = Ids[1];
                ViewBag.VisitStatus_Cd = Ids[2];
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Are you trying to share data between users? Or are you worried that the data will be shared?

Comment: That should not be possible, since TempData uses Session as its storage unless you have a custom TempDataProvider, and Session is bound to a specific users session id.  You are probably just opening up another tab in your browser and seeing the tempdata, which it will because tabs share session data.

Answer (score 0):

Your pages are being cached by IIS. For MVC applications you will need to add .cshtml to the list of file extensions that are not allowed to cache. Please see the following link for the solution to stop caching. (http://lionsden.co.il/codeden/?p=446)